# OpenCV Error with cvCalibrateCamera2

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some problem running OpenCV programs with `cvCalibrateCamera2`.

This has been tried with examples from [here](http://vgl-ait.org/cvwiki/doku.php?id=opencv:tutorial:camera_calibration)
and Oreilly "Learning OpenCV" example ch11 ex11 (codes downloadable from [here](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596516130/)). The error is the same. The codes run through `cvFindChessboardCorners`, `cvDrawChessboardCorners` etc. with no problem, and they only fail at `cvCalibrateCamera2` with the following information:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_dst.fixedType()) in convertPointsHomogeneous, file /root/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 1034
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /root/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:1034: error: (-215) _dst.fixedType() in function convertPointsHomogeneous
```

Can you tell what the problem is, or point direction to where it could be?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating into the OpenCV 3.1 source codes, I think the problem is with OpenCV itself, since the error comes from variables created and passed around within the library. I tried a lower version of OpenCV (2.4.13) and that fixed the problem.